# Made a mistake of connecting pin-1 NC of MPU6500. Will it affect my pcb?

Tags: imu

Yeah I made a mistake but the pcb is on the way and I cannot cancel it. I mistakenly connected the pin-1 NC of MPU6500 to VDD(Yeah even bigger mistake). So anyone who has worked with MPU6500 know if it will affect the IC function or it will still work properly?

Comment: You could always rework the PCB by cutting the trace or even completely removing that pad. (removing pads is easy, it happens all the time when you don't want it to :)

Comment: Thanks Unimportant, but the pcb will we assembled...and I don't think cutting the trace would be possible

Comment: Is the trace under the chip? Those pins may not be connected to anything internally so it may not matter, but I wouldn't take the chance unless you have one to spare.

Comment: NC can indicate that the pin is not connected to anything, or that you must not connect to it because it is connected to circuits internally (often because the manufacture uses this pin during testing). The datasheet indicates: *do not connect*.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet says "do not connect" about that pin.

That is the best answer you have unless you ask the manufacturer. We cannot possibly know what is the internal function of that pin, or if it matters, or if it is even connected.

The chip status is also "not recommended for new designs" so it might not be available for long. So while you have to change the PCB anyway, you might as well change the chip to something that is future proof.

Answer (score 0):

As it's a QFN  solder  is required to complete the bad connection, so
blank out the "pin 1" solder hole in the solder mask (this probably requires replacing the solder mask), that will prevent that connection from being made to the chip.  After solder and wash you could add some insulating resin in the gap.

or speak to the board manufacturer they may have a better solution.